# New update or a bug in the main & meta page display of a question's activity information

Tags: discussion

Today I saw this

[image]

But in the past, I used to see them in the right-hand top corner of the (already not-so-nice) layout.

Is this a permanent or a bug?

Is this added in order to make way for ads (atop the already to-be occupied space of hot-meta posts https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387546/we-re-removing-hot-meta-posts-from-stack-overflows-sidebar-for-now-moderator)?

> PS1: please only see the highlighted part `;-)`
>
> PS2: I know that the removal of hot-meta posts column is only for stack-overflow (for now). But I suspect it will soon be rolled-out throughout the community.

Comment: I was just wondering the same thing...

Comment: @CarLaTeX I think that the product is becoming more important than the process itself `;-)`

Comment: I like the new layout, imho that is the right place for this info. Being able to see directly that a question is old, is imho quite a help.

Comment: Related question on the main meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331349/why-are-the-sidebar-stats-for-a-question-now-under-the-title